# Extend all views with custom data and filters in Sails.js

Tags: templates, view, sails.js

I'm developing a Sails.js application and I want to extend all views with custom data and functions.

What would be the best course of action to do so?

I've tried to create a policy to do so, but policies are only applied to routes with controllers.

Answer (score 1):

## Custom data

You can use a custom hook in order to achieve that.

Create a file at the specified path: `api/hooks/viewsGlobals/index.js` with the following content:

```js
module.exports = function viewsGlobals (sails) {
  return {
    routes: {
      before: {
        // This middleware will be executed for every request.
        '*': function (req, res, next) {

          // Using condition to filter out static file requests.
          if (req.accepted.some(function (type) {
            return type.value === 'text/html';
          })) {
            res.locals.someData = {
              // Place your custom data here.
            };
          }

          return next();
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

## Custom filters

Create a file at the following path: `config/view-filters/toUpper.js` and the following content:

```js
// Replace this with templating engine that you use.
var swig = require('swig');

// Use the API of your templating engine to add custom filter.
swig.setFilter('toUpper', function (value) {
  return value.toUpperCase();
});
```